# Problema al agregar materialize a mi proyecto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, materialize

tengo una consulta estuvo creando una pagina web con stack MERN, al que luego de crear una interfaz decidi agregar materialize para que sea mas facil llevar a cabo el diseño del sitio. Lo que ocurrio es que al agregarlo se desconfiguro toda la interfaz que habia creado en un principio. Adjunto 2 imagenes del antes y despues. Desde ya muchas gracias[image: Despues]

[image: Antes]

Comment: elimina materialize, y listo. Tu pregunta no esta bien formulada y podria ser cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que materialize css sobreescribe los diseños css de los elementos HTML.
deberias de agregar a los controles una clase materialize que se llama: browser-default
Ejemplo con JQUERY.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button, select, input, textarea").addClass("browser-default");
});
```

O agregas a mano la clase browser-default en cada elemento que no quieras que aplique efecto materialize.
Ejemplo:

```
<select class="browser-default">
<option>1<option>
<option>1<option>
```

Tambien te recomiendo que descargues el materializecss eligiendo lo que necesitas desde el siguiente link:

https://materialize.khophi.co/